# Fetching sub localities through a zip code

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoding-api, geocode

How can I fetch sub localities or sub sub localities through geocoding API by passing zip code of that area? Currently I am only getiing postal_localities.

I tried this
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=122001

I got localities through it, but I also want it to return sub localities

Answer (score 0):

That feature is not available in the Geocoding API; you can file a feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188871&template=788906).

The `postcode_localities` in the Geocoding API offer a way to "disambiguate" the relationship between postal codes and localities which are *kind of adjacent* types; in most places postal codes are contained by a single locality, but in some places the relationship is reversed or there is no *containment* relation but instead an *overlap* relation, and in those cases `postcode_localities` help.

Sublocalities are contained by localities, which means they are "2 levels under" those postal codes (that contain/overlap localities), so the relation is not direct. Based on that, I don't think it would make sense to expose that in the same way.

Besides, the Geocoding API is a *search* kind of API, not a database, so it doesn't really support the *find all places of type X under condition Y* kind of queries.